# Vuetify Combobox issue when clicking on the edge of another combobox or outside of combobox

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, combobox, vuetify.js

I have a simple page that uses vuetify combobxes and vuetify inputs. I have been working on a way to switch focus of the comboboxes when an added item is confirmed to be added to the list. This works correctly and the focus does take hold.

The issue I am having is when there is text in the combobox and you click anywhere else outside of the combobox or on the top edge of another combobx,  I get the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

If I click directly in the next input the focus changes as expected

I think this error is coming from this method

```
thisFocus(event) {
      const controlName = this.setToTitleCase(event.target.id);

      if (this.currentFocus && this.showDialog &&
        event.target.id !== 'condition') {
          this.nextFocus = controlName;
          return
        }
      this.currentFocus = controlName;
    }
```

I also have an example setup in a code sandbox as well you can find it here
[Sample code with error](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-resonance-lqg6z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I am looking for some help to resolve this error or at least get pointed in the right direction

EDIT: To better clarify this issue, what I have gathered is the control highlighted in blue in the image below is the complete v-combobox component of vuetify. 
[image: vuetify v-combobox]

The v-combobox component has another component inside the combobox component used for messaging as shown in the highlighted area of the image below. 
[image: v-combobox message area]

The issue I am having is that if you happen to click on that message area rather than the input component. I believe I understand why the event.relatedTarget is null but I can't figure out what I need to make sure the focus goes to the correct input component if you happen to click on the message area.

Comment: you have an event on focusout called checkNewItem. event.relatedTarget is null in there and error is because of that. check it out.

Comment: I updated the Question to clarify a little more on what my issue is